# Converting time vectors into Julian days

Tags: r, time-series, julian-date

I have a .txt file in which the second column represents the measuring time in seconds (starting date of measurements is 04/01/15) during 367 days (end date of measurements is 04/01/16). The third and so on are measured variables.

In my analysis I need to have this second column in Julian days (when dealing with this type of date I usually use as "origin" 01/01/1992) in order to assess with other variables in other files that have already the date in Julian time. I could also use the calendar date instead if I had it!

Example of the file:

(First day)

```
091.00000   0.00    102.63  16.79   81.40   5.07    144.20  0.00
091.00069   60.00   102.63  16.80   81.30   5.86    136.00  0.00
091.00139   120.00  102.63  16.75   81.20   2.46    144.20  0.00
```

(...)

```
091.99931   86340.00    102.53  17.09   82.60   1.60    117.00  0.00
```

(Second day)

```
092.00000   0.00    102.53  16.96   82.60   1.56    115.00  0.00
092.00069   60.00   102.53  16.87   82.90   1.38    114.70  0.00
092.00139   120.00  102.53  17.01   82.90   1.13    110.30  0.00
```

(...)

```
092.99931   86340.00    102.44  17.38   87.10   1.75    116.00  0.00
```

This happens for all days during the entire 367 days (corresponding to a total of 526970 measurements) and I have this all together in one file. There might be missing data recording, so I can use missing values (NA) in those gaps.

I'm using R.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Some example data would it more clear.

Comment: I edited the question, hope it is more clear now. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second column seems to be the number of seconds since the current day started. 24 hours / day * 3600 seconds per hour is 86400 seconds per day. So `SecondColumn/86400` gives the decimals of the Julian date. The second columns doesn't hold information on the date itself.

Comment: Ok, so the first column that I have is already the Julian date (0.9100000, 0.9100069,...). then I must be doing something wrong when I'm plotting the data with this column as x-axis. I basically use tm2_1min=dat2$V1 (first column) for x-axis and atmos_press_1min=dat2$V3 (third column) for one e.g. variable and then plot(tm2_1min,atmos_press_1min,type="l",xaxt = "n") with axis(side=1,at=datJ,lab=labJ) defined as datJ=seq(from=julian(04,01,2015, origin=c(1,1,1992)), to=julian(02,04,2016, origin=c(1,1,1992)))
labJ=seq.dates("04/01/2015","02/04/2016",by="days")

Comment: Hey, I've managed to resolve my problem. the Julia days that I have in the file start counting from 2015 and not from 1992 as I'm used to. In addition,   when the counting reaches 365 it goes back again to 091.000 and R was causing trouble for that when I wanted to plot the data. So i just corrected the counting to keep going from 365 up to 456. I can plot nicely now the data. thanks for the hint btw.